# Generating permutations using bash

Tags: bash, shell, permutation

is it possible to write a bash script that can read in each line from a file and generate permutations (without repetition) for each? Using awk / perl is fine.

```
File
----
ab
abc


Output
------
ab
ba
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Comment: I like bashing things... :P

Comment: Can you assume that each line of input has no repeated characters?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pure bash (using `local`, faster, but can't beat the other answer using awk below, or the Python below):

```
perm() {
  local items="$1"
  local out="$2"
  local i
  [[ "$items" == "" ]] && echo "$out" && return
  for (( i=0; i<${#items}; i++ )) ; do
    perm "${items:0:i}${items:i+1}" "$out${items:i:1}"
  done
  }
while read line ; do perm $line ; done < File
```

Pure bash (using subshell, much slower):

```
perm() {
  items="$1"
  out="$2"
  [[ "$items" == "" ]] && echo "$out" && return
  for (( i=0; i<${#items}; i++ )) ; do
    ( perm "${items:0:i}${items:i+1}" "$out${items:i:1}" )
  done
  }
while read line ; do perm $line ; done < File
```

Since asker mentioned Perl is fine, I think Python 2.6+/3.X is fine, too:

```
python -c "from itertools import permutations as p ; print('\n'.join([''.join(item) for line in open('File') for item in p(line[:-1])]))"
```

For Python 2.5+/3.X:

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.5

# http://stackoverflow.com/questions/104420/how-to-generate-all-permutations-of-a-list-in-python/104436#104436
def all_perms(str):
    if len(str) <=1:
        yield str
    else:
        for perm in all_perms(str[1:]):
            for i in range(len(perm)+1):
                #nb str[0:1] works in both string and list contexts
                yield perm[:i] + str[0:1] + perm[i:]

print('\n'.join([''.join(item) for line in open('File') for item in all_perms(line[:-1])]))
```

On my computer using a bigger test file:

```
First Python code
  Python 2.6:     0.038s
  Python 3.1:     0.052s
Second Python code
  Python 2.5/2.6: 0.055s
  Python 3.1:     0.072s
awk:              0.332s
Bash (local):     2.058s
Bash (subshell): 22+s
```

Comment: nice bash, but too slow if length gets bigger

Comment: Also, you can do math in array slicing without `$(())` and you can omit the dollar signs: `( perm "${items:0:i}${items:i+1}" "$out${items:i:1} )"

Comment: on my computer, awk is always the fastest.

Comment: @user131527, what was the Python version you using? If it's 2.5, then that result is incorrect. My original python code doesn't work for 2.5 and 3.1, and it runs slower than awk, but it's incorrect. I have updated the code and they all are much faster than awk.

Comment: @ShellFish I was referring to ghostdog74's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3846470/242583) which is written in Awk. As you can see we engaged some discussions above, that's why I added a time test for his or her Awk code. I should have been more clearer as I editing my answer.

Comment: Ah I see, great post though!

Comment: This is Awesome. My brain is not up to the mark... Great logic

Answer (score 30):

I know I am a little late to the game but why not brace expansion?

For example:

```
echo {a..z}{0..9}
```

Outputs:

```
a0 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6 a7 a8 a9 b0 b1 b2 b3 b4 b5 b6 b7 b8 b9 c0 c1 c2 c3 c4 c5 c6 c7 c8 c9 d0 d1 d2 d3 d4 d5 d6 d7 d8 d9 e0 e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 f0 f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 g0 g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8 g9 h0 h1 h2 h3 h4 h5 h6 h7 h8 h9 i0 i1 i2 i3 i4 i5 i6 i7 i8 i9 j0 j1 j2 j3 j4 j5 j6 j7 j8 j9 k0 k1 k2 k3 k4 k5 k6 k7 k8 k9 l0 l1 l2 l3 l4 l5 l6 l7 l8 l9 m0 m1 m2 m3 m4 m5 m6 m7 m8 m9 n0 n1 n2 n3 n4 n5 n6 n7 n8 n9 o0 o1 o2 o3 o4 o5 o6 o7 o8 o9 p0 p1 p2 p3 p4 p5 p6 p7 p8 p9 q0 q1 q2 q3 q4 q5 q6 q7 q8 q9 r0 r1 r2 r3 r4 r5 r6 r7 r8 r9 s0 s1 s2 s3 s4 s5 s6 s7 s8 s9 t0 t1 t2 t3 t4 t5 t6 t7 t8 t9 u0 u1 u2 u3 u4 u5 u6 u7 u8 u9 v0 v1 v2 v3 v4 v5 v6 v7 v8 v9 w0 w1 w2 w3 w4 w5 w6 w7 w8 w9 x0 x1 x2 x3 x4 x5 x6 x7 x8 x9 y0 y1 y2 y3 y4 y5 y6 y7 y8 y9 z0 z1 z2 z3 z4 z5 z6 z7 z8 z9
```

Another useful example:

```
for X in {a..z}{a..z}{0..9}{0..9}{0..9}
    do echo $X;
done
```

Comment: This is cool, but it creates permutation *with repetition* (which, coincidentally, is what I came here looking for.)  The question seems to be about plain permutations, which don't allow repetition.

Comment: @SigmaX, then you can pipe the endresult through sort | uniq, e.g. echo {a..z}{0..9} | tr ' ' '\n' | sort |  uniq

Comment: @Aviadisto That would remove duplicates (if I understand you), but I was concerned with the repetition of elements within each permutation (which is something else).  Looking at this answer again, though, I realize that it computes a cross product of two sets, not a permutation.  So it neither answers the original question nor what I came looking for!  I hope I didn't use this code somewhere important, lol.

Comment: I'm disappointed that this is the top voted answer when, as @SigmaX points out, it doesn't work. The very first expansion of `{a..c}{a..c}{a..c}` is `aaa`! Switching to letters and numbers in the answer obscures this fact, and verges on bad faith. Downvoted.

Answer (score 10):

Using the [`crunch`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/crunch-wordlist/) util, and `bash`:

```
while read a; do crunch 0 0 -p "$a"; done 2> /dev/null < File
```

Output:

```
ab
ba
abc
acb
bac
bca
cab
cba
```

Tutorial here https://pentestlab.blog/2012/07/12/creating-wordlists-with-crunch/

Comment: @agc yeah, you're right. I didn't do it because man pages are good with examples. Also easy to find googling it. Anyway, I added a simple one with a tutorial link.

Comment: @agc, it would be nigh impossible for any code in an answer to improve on the code in the question. If the OP is looking for a strategy for generating permutations, then a reference to something that does just that seems like a good start.

Comment: @ghoti, Re "*the code in the question*": there isn't any code in the OP, just data:  please clarify.

Comment: @jyz, Added working code that answers Q.  We should delete these comments.

Answer (score 8):

A faster version using awk

```
function permute(s, st,     i, j, n, tmp) {
    n = split(s, item,//)
    if (st > n) {  print s; return }
    for (i=st; i<=n; i++) {
        if (i != st) {
         tmp = item[st]; item[st] = item[i]; item[i] = tmp
         nextstr = item[1]
         for (j=2; j<=n; j++) nextstr = nextstr delim item[j]
        }else {
          nextstr = s
        }
       permute(nextstr, st+1)
       n = split(s, item, //)
   }
}
{ permute($0,1) }
```

usage:

```
$ awk -f permute.awk file
```

Answer (score 5):

See the [Perl Cookbook](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/perl/cookbook/ch04_20.htm) for permutation examples. They're word/number oriented but a simple `split()`/`join()` on your above example will suffice.

Comment: Downvoted why ? The OP specifically says Perl is an acceptable solution

Answer (score 3):

**Bash word-list/dictionary/permutation generator:**

The following Bash code generates 3 character permutation over 0-9, a-z, A-Z. It gives you (10+26+26)^3 = 238,328 words in output.

It's not very scalable as you can see you need to increase the number of `for` loop to increase characters in combination. It would be much faster to write such thing in assembly or C using recursion to increase speed. The Bash code is only for demonstration.

**P.S.**
You can populate `$list` variable with `list=$(cat input.txt)`

```
#!/bin/bash

list=`echo {0..9} {a..z} {A..Z}`

for c1 in $list
do
        for c2 in $list
        do  
                for c3 in $list
                do  
                         echo $c1$c2$c3
                done
        done
done
```

SAMPLE OUTPUT:

```
000
001
002
003
004
005
...
...
...
ZZU
ZZV
ZZW
ZZX
ZZY
ZZZ
[babil@quad[13:27:37][~]> wc -l t.out 
238328 t.out
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ ruby -ne '$_.chomp.chars.to_a.permutation{|x| puts x.join}' file # ver 1.9.1
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you can never have enogh cryptic Bash-oneliners:

```
while read s;do p="$(echo "$s"|sed -e 's/./&,/g' -e 's/,$//')";eval "printf "%s\\\\n" "$(eval 'echo "$(printf "{'"$p"'}%.0s" {0..'"$((${#s}-1))"'})"')"|grep '\(.\)\1*.*\1' -v";echo;done <f
```

It's pretty fast - at least on my machine here:

```
$ time while read s;do p="$(echo "$s"|sed -e 's/./&,/g' -e 's/,$//')";eval "printf "%s\\\\n" "$(eval 'echo "$(printf "{'"$p"'}%.0s" {0..'"$((${#s}-1))"'})"')"|grep '\(.\)\1*.*\1' -v";echo;done <f >/dev/null 

real 0m0.021s
user 0m0.000s
sys  0m0.004s
```

But be aware that this one will eat a lot of memory when you go beyond 8 characters...

Answer (score 0):

**file named input:**

a
b
c
d

**If you want the output:**

a b
a c
a d
b b
b c
b d
c c
c d
d d

**You can try the following bash script:**

```
lines=$(wc -l input | awk '{print $1}')
for ((i=1 ; i<=$lines ; i++)); do
        x=$(sed -n ''$i' p' input)
        sed -n ''$i',$ p' input > tmp
        for j in $(cat tmp) ; do
                echo $x $j
        done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Hows about this one

```
lines="a b c"
for i in $lines; do
        echo $i >tmp
        for j in $lines ; do
                echo $i $j
        done
done
```

it will print

```
a a
a b
a c
b a
b b
b c
c a
c b
c c
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a 4-lines-bash joke - permutation of 4 letters/names:

```
while read line
    do 
    [ $(sed -r "s/(.)/\1\n/g" <<<$line | sort | uniq | wc -l) -eq 5 ] && echo $line 
    done <<<$(echo -e {A..D}{A..D}{A..D}{A..D}"\n") | sed -r "s/A/Adams /;s/B/Barth /; s/C/Cecil /; s/D/Devon /;"

Adams Barth Cecil Devon 
Adams Barth Devon Cecil 
...
```

I like Bash! :-)