# Generate all possible strings from a list of token

Tags: python, bash, language-agnostic

I have a list of tokens, like:

```
hel
lo
bye
```

and i want to generate all the possible combinations of such strings, like:

```
hello
lohel
helbye
byehel
lobye
byelo
```

Language is not important, any advice?

I found [Generating permutations using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846123/generating-permutations-using-bash), but this makes permutation on a single line.

Comment: LucaB, I don't think "hello" is a permutation of "hel", "lo", "bye" in the normal understanding of "permutation". Specifically, a permutation of a set cannot leave out members of the set. So answerers have to choose between what you explicitly asked for, and the sample output you show. Probably "combinations" is what you meant, as @Sven pointed out.

Comment: You're right, I meant combinations. I'll update my question.

Comment: just to [link this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5898031/875020) here for people looking for ALL combinations

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your example can be written in Python as

```
from itertools import combinations
print list(combinations(["hel", "lo", "bye"], 2))
```

To combine the output to strings again:

```
print ["".join(a) for a in combinations(["hel", "lo", "bye"], 2)]
```

If you interested in the actual implementation of this function, have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

Comment: Results in: <itertools.combinations object at 0xb7d1370c>

Comment: Still not one per line as requested.

Comment: Can't find this request, even after reading the post again.  Furthermore, it's rather trivial to change this.

Comment: "but this makes permutation on a single line." implies that he wants one per line (and his example output show it as such).

Comment: @kanaka, it seems to me that the OP is only asking for advices, not complete solutions.

Answer (score 8):

[`itertools.permutations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) can do that for you.

```
>>> l = ['hel', 'lo', 'bye']
>>> list(itertools.permutations(l, 2))
[('hel', 'lo'), ('hel', 'bye'), ('lo', 'hel'), ('lo', 'bye'), ('bye', 'hel'), ('bye', 'lo')]
```

Or if you want combinations, you can use [`itertools.combinations`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations).

```
>>> l = ['hel', 'lo', 'bye']
>>> list(itertools.combinations(l, 2))
[('hel', 'lo'), ('hel', 'bye'), ('lo', 'bye')]
```

Comment: Deducing from the example, the OP actually wants combinations, not permutations.

Comment: Not exactly one per line, nor words.

Comment: @kanaka, It's only a matter of joining strings, printing and formatting.

Answer (score 3):

Given that other languages are acceptable:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Algorithm::Combinatorics qw(permutations);

my $data = [ qw( hel lo bye ) ];
my $it = permutations($data);

while ( my $p = $it->next ) {
    print @$p, "\n";
}
```

```
hellobye
helbyelo
lohelbye
lobyehel
byehello
byelohel
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['hel', 'lo', 'bye']
print '\n'.join(''.join(x) for x in itertools.permutations(a, 2))
```

Comment: This only does 2 token combinations not all possible as requested.

Comment: and yet his desired output had 2 token combinations as well :)

Answer (score 2):

Easy in python with itertools.

Here is the token permutation example:

```
import itertools

tokens = ["hel", "lo", "bye"]

for i in range(1, len(tokens) + 1):
    for p in itertools.permutations(tokens, i):
        print "".join(p)
```

Alternatively, this treats each character as a token:

```
import itertools

tokens = ["hel", "lo", "bye"]

chars = "".join(tokens)
for i in range(1, len(chars) + 1):
    for p in itertools.permutations(chars, i):
        print "".join(p)
```

Comment: It gives all permutations of all chars.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want `permutations`:

```
from itertools import permutations

# easy way to make a list for words
words = 'hel lo bye'.split()

# fetch two-word permutations, joined into a string
for word in [''.join(s) for s in permutations(words,2)]:
    print word
```

#### Output:

```
hello
helbye
lohel
lobye
byehel
byelo
```

Answer (score 1):

Python has a [permutations](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) too. :)

Answer (score 0):

**Update:** I see I wasn't explicit enough.

Haskell has a [permutations](http://haskell.org/ghc/docs/6.12.2/html/libraries/base-4.2.0.1/Data-List.html#v%3Apermutations) function that would help:

```
import Data.List
permutations ["hel","lo","bye"] ==
[["hel","lo","bye"],["lo","hel","bye"],["bye","lo","hel"],
 ["lo","bye","hel"],["bye","hel","lo"],["hel","bye","lo"]]
```

If you want each permutation concatenated, use

```
map concat (permutations ["hel","lo","bye"]) ==
["hellobye","lohelbye","byelohel","lobyehel","byehello","helbyelo"]
```

If you actually want **combinations** of two substrings (like your example output) instead of all **permutations** of substrings, as @Sven noticed, use the Math.Combinatorics.Graph module and:

```
map concat (combinationsOf 2 ["hel","lo","bye"])
```

That matches your example data in some respects but not others. I could go on to speculate that you want "all possible strings" as the title says, or all permutations of two-token subsets, or what have you, but it's kind of pointless to speculate since you've already accepted an answer.

Comment: Nice, but this permutes all letters on a given string, not set of strings.

Comment: LucaB, permutations will work on any iterable. Look at the examples in python.

Comment: @LucaB, look again... the function permutes a list. If you pass it a list of characters (a string), it will permute those characters. If you pass it a list of strings, it will permute that list of strings.

Comment: @LucaB, if you downvoted this answer because you thought the function I was talking about only worked on strings, consider changing your vote. In Haskell, strings are lists, and the function works on any list.