# generate text file from set of character

Tags: bash

I want to generate one text file containing all combinations possible from a restricted character set into bash , or may be python

For example 
I have

```
aAbBc01+
```

and I want to have all combinations 9 and 10 character long start with

```
aaaaaaaaa
```

finish with

```
++++++++++
```

passing through

```
+++++++++
aaaaaaaaaa
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already discussed in the [forum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846123/generating-permutations-using-bash)

For python:

```
python -c "from itertools import permutations as p ; print('\n'.join([''.join(item) for line in open('File') for item in p(line[:-1])]))"
```

where File contains your input string

For bash -- Much slower

```
perm() {
  items="$1"
  out="$2"
  [[ "$items" == "" ]] && echo "$out" && return
  for (( i=0; i<${#items}; i++ )) ; do
    ( perm "${items:0:i}${items:i+1}" "$out${items:i:1}" )
    done
  }
while read line ; do perm $line ; done < File
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a python solution:

```
def combinations(chars,length,result="",place=0):
    if place>=length:
        print result;
        return
    for i in range(length):
        combinations(chars,length,result+chars[i],place+1)
```

this function gets a string and desired length for results, and prints all the combinations of characters from it who has the specified length.

if you want the combinations of length 9 or 10, just call

```
combinations("aAbBc01+",9)
combinations("aAbBc01+",10)
```

and redirect the output to the text file