# Multiplication of lines in bash

Tags: linux, bash, text

I want to make something like multiplication:

File1:

```
aa
bb
```

File2:

```
cc
dd
```

File3:

```
eee
fff
ggg
```

I want a result like:

```
aa cc eee
aa cc fff
aa cc ggg
bb dd eee
bb dd fff
bb dd ggg
```

File1 & File2 first element will multiply every element of File3, and same as second element of File1 & File2 multiply with every element of File3.

Comment: 1. Why? / 2. Do you have to use `bash`? No Python? / 3. Basically you are looking for [permutations](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3846123/1525423)

Comment: @Finwood im making little bot with bash and some binaries, so i have to go through bash...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This would work:

```
$ join -j 9999 <(paste file1 file2) file3
 aa cc eee
 aa cc fff
 aa cc ggg
 bb dd eee
 bb dd fff
 bb dd ggg
```

It joins on a non-existing field (field 9999), which creates the Cartesian product of the input files. For the input files, `paste file1 file2` combines the first two files into one, and `join` uses process substitution.

A slight snag is that there is a space introduced on each line; to get rid of that, you can pipe to sed:

```
join -j 9999 <(paste file1 file2) file3 | sed 's/^ //'
```

or specify an output format:

```
join -j 9999 -o 1.1,1.2,2.1 <(paste file1 file2) file3
```

Comment: or use `-o1.1,1.2,2.1`

Comment: one additional minor note, it's convention to use `-j 9` or `-j 9999` as the fake key.

Comment: @karakfa ...and added.

Comment: Thanks Mr. Benjamin, Solved problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You could use a nested for loop.

```
for ab in $(paste -d ' ' File1 File2); do
  for c in $(cat File3); do
    echo "$ab $c"
  done
done
```

It doesn’t scale, obviously, but it may be enough for your use case.

Comment: Thanks for quick answer, but it got wrong output. Not same as result example

Comment: you're computing the cross product of all three files,  different from what OP asks for.

Comment: @karakfa: Oh, you’re right. I’ve corrected my answer.