# How can I delete the numbers from the output, that has same numbers in it?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, permutation

A nice user solved my problem, so I changed my question, now its not the same as before the other one was. 
My permutation look like this now:

`x=3

for i in $(eval echo "{1..$x}{1..$x}{1..$x}"); do

echo "$i"

done`

How can I get just these numbers (123,132,231,213,321,312) from the output with two "for" periods and with "seq" command?

Comment: Your output makes no sense, it doesn't appear to follow any pattern.

Comment: Your first "permutation" prints only empty lines: `i` is not `X`.

Comment: I didn't even need `eval`. Try `input=2; for i in {1..$input}{1..$input}{1..$input}  ;  do echo $i;  done`. Good luck.

Comment: oh sorry, I wanted to write x.

Comment: thank you very very much! And what if I want to filter them and get only those, which arent contain the same number? I know I should use "for" and "seq", to get it somehow.

Comment: @shellter In bash braces are expanded before variables. You might have zsh as your shell?

Comment: @shellter You cant use variables in brace expansion as braces are evaluated first.

Comment: @andlrc   (and @123) . It really works for me, but I'm using ksh93. Forgot about one of the corner cases where `bash` and `ksh` work differently. Thanks for the reminder!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make permutation in bash with N! input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639939/how-to-make-permutation-in-bash-with-n-input)

Comment: I will delete that topic. Sorry for that.
edit: I cant..

Comment: Please don't change your question, especially if the old question already has answers. Ask a new question, instead.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to be able to dynamically set 3 in `{1..3}` something like `{1..$x}`. If you try that you will experience that the output will be `{1..3}` and not the expected `1 2 3`. This is because braces are expanded before variables.

What you need to use is `eval echo "{1..$x}"` which will indeed output `1 2 3`.  And in a for loop you could use a command substitution:

```
x=3
for i in $(eval echo "{1..$x}{1..$x}{1..$x}"); do
  echo "$i"
done
```

Comment: can you please help me how to filter them? I know there are much better version of this, but Id like to do it like this. The output without the same numbers like: 111, 112, etc. I have to do it with two for periods in each other.. and have to use seq command. (sorry for my bad english, Im trying..:D)

Comment: @hategrip So you  want consider 123 and 321 as the same?

Comment: no, I dont. I want to have just: 123, 132, 231, 213, 312, 321. :) ! but I must have to do it with this beginning, which you have written for me.

Comment: @hategrip You asked this question two days ago? Why ask it again?

Comment: Because people didnt understand me, but know I understand my question(!), so i started again.

Comment: do you have any ideas how to do it like this?