# Generating permutations of persons/strings using bash

Tags: bash, permutation

I have a file with names. Each line represents a connection between the persons.
But there also might be only one name in a line, too.

```
Donald Duck;Daisy Duck;Della Duck;
Fethry Duck;Dudly D. Duck;Donald Duck;
Della Duck;Dudly D. Duck;Moby Duck;
Dugan Duck;Donald Duck;Dimwitty Duck;Whitewater Duck;
Lonesome Duck;
```

I would like to permutate through the lines. To result should be like

```
Donald Duck;Daisy Duck
Donald Duck;Della Duck
Daisy Duck;Della Duck
Fethry Duck;Dudly D. Duck
Fethry Duck;Donald Duck
Dudly D. Duck;Donald Duck
Della Duck;Dudly D. Duck
Della Duck;Moby Duck
Dudly D. Duck;Moby Duck
Dugan Duck;Donald Duck
Dugan Duck;Dimwitty Duck
Dugan Duck;Whitewater Duck
Donald Duck;Dimwitty Duck
Donald Duck;Whitewater Duck
Dimwitty Duck;Whitewater Duck
Lonesome Duck;
```

The solution provided on [Generating permutations using bash](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3846321/8584652) does not consider words but single characters.

Comment: Should the desired output be updated to reflect Lonesome Duck?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you want 2-combinations of names in each line. A bash script for this could be something like that:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=\; read -r -a names; do
    if ((${#names[@]} == 1)); then # if we have only one name, just echo it
        echo "${names[0]}"
    else
        for ((i = 0; i < ${#names[@]} - 1; ++i)); do
            for ((j = i + 1; j < ${#names[@]}; ++j)); do
                echo "${names[i]};${names[j]}"
            done
        done
    fi
done < names.txt
```

Comment: great! I am sorry, I forgot to write that there is also the possibility that there is only one name in a line `Duck;`. That should still be printed as it is (updated my question).

Comment: This is my answer exactly! You got here first. +1

Comment: I'd suggest the condition for the `i` loop could be `i < ${#names[@]} - 1` -- as it currently stands, the `j` loop has zero iterations when `i` is the last index.

Comment: @glennjackman It is a *micro optimization*, but your suggestion is fine and I complied with it.